# How can I connect to SQLite on an FTP server in R?

Tags: r, ftp, sftp, rcurl, rsqlite

I have a SQLite database located on a Windows VM that can be accessed via sftp. I am unsure how to access it from within R.

Currently, I can use RCurl to get a listing of files, but really can't figure out the rest. Is it possible to do such a thing?

The `my_sqlite.db` is located in the `C:\my_data` folder and shows up as `root` folder when I use something like WinSCP.

Here's an example:

```
library("RCurl")
sftp_url = "sftp://00.000.000.000/my_sqlite.db" 
sftp_userpwd = "my_username:my_password" # not sure how to use this
sftp_port = 22 # not sure how to use this

db_con = DBI::dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(),
                        dbname = sftp_url)
```

Once I have this connection, I want to be able to read/write using `RSQLite::dbSendQuery` and things of that nature

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you'll need to download the entire database file, modify the data locally and then upload it again. I'm not sure FTP supports blockwise access, and then SQLite would need to support FTP access too.